# Usage of BindableBase in classic MVVM design

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am a little bit confused with usage of BindableBase class and how to apply this "new" mechanism to the classic MVVM design.

Briefly, the question is the following: How to use correctly BindableBase class when we have reference to the model in our view-model class?

**Details:**

Classical MVVM pattern: View <-> View-Model -> Model

As we see View-Model in this scheme knows about Model, but Model knows nothing about View and View-Model.

If we implement this approach, we will have something like this:

```
// Model
class Task
{...}

// View-Model
class TaskViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private readonly Task _task;

    public TaskViewModel(Task task)
    {
        _task = task;
    }
    ...
}
```

Let's imaging that Task class has 'Subject' property and we should show this data. So according to MVVM I should:

Create duplication of 'Subject' property in View-Model:

```
// View-Model
class TaskViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public String Subject
    {
        get{ return _task.Subject; }
        set
        {
            _task.Subject = value;

           // I can't use SetProperty(ref _task.Subject, value)
           // it's contradict c# syntax
           OnPropertyChanged("Subject");
        }
    }
}
```

As you see I can't use SetProperty method for such design and the only way it's calling of raw onPropertyChanged method.

It seems that SetProperty is the biggest benefit of BindableBase class and it's very strange that we can't use it in such direct and common implementation of MVVM. So I thought maybe I missed something or work incorrectly with the specified class.

Do you know how to use BindableBase for the specified design and get some code improvement?

Thanks

Comment: I think the viewmodel doesn't know anything about the view so...Classical MVVM pattern: View -> View-Model -> Model

Comment: Disagree, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel
View has a reference to View-Model through DataContext

Comment: Ops, I typo :) I thought about View. In 'pure' MVVM it shouldn't, but there is no strict restriction as far as I know, and usually it has reference, because it's convenient. Anyway, it is not connected with subj.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, your `ViewModel` is exposing `Model` properties to your `View`. This is *fine* however it becomes quite ridiculous if your `Model` has lots of properties that need to be exposed. Can you imagine having to create properties for a `Model` that has 20+ properties?

Instead, you should expose the `Model` to the `View` using a **property** inside your `ViewModel`.

```
public MyClass Model { get; private set; }
```

*Note: This too can implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.*

And the properties in your `Model` should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, or in your case, `BindableBase`.

```
public class MyClass : BindableBase
```

Your `View` can then bind directly to the `Model` property. This may seem like you're breaking the design pattern however this is not the case, your `View` still knows nothing about your `Model`, however it simply makes assumptions to what properties it's expecting, therefore your classes are still decoupled.

The only downside here is that your `Model` now depends on `BindableBase`, this isn't the end of the world but if you are in a situation where you **can't** modify the `Model` classes, then your current approach is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you, the situation with usage of BindableBase class as base class for the model was unclear for me.

Answer (score 1):

Like *Mike Eason* said, it is fine to expose your model, one of the main goals of the ViewModel is to get the Model ready for your view. That said, I tend to only expose the model for read-only views myself.

You could inherit from BindableBase and create a method to allow you to alter the Model's properties in the same way you do fields.

```
public class ViewModelBase : BindableBase
{
    protected bool SetProperty(
        Func<bool> isValueNew,
        Action setValue,
        [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (isValueNew())
        {
            return false;
        }

        setValue();
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
}
```

The isValueNew Func is for determining if the value is different or not. You could then use it like the following:

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly MyModel myModel = new MyModel();

    public string Name
    {
        get { return myModel.Name; }
        set
        {
            if (SetProperty(() => myModel.Name == value, () => myModel.Name = value))
            {
                // Do something here since the value was changed.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That's the easiest way I can think of to achieve what you seem to be after.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep your setter for the Subject property simple.

Consider loading the data from your model first and then assigning the data to your view-model properties.

```
class TaskViewModel : BindableBase
{
    LoadData()
    {
       Subject = GetSubject(); // Relies on model
    }

    string _subject = null;
    public String Subject
    {
        get{ return _subject; }
        set
        {
            _subject = value;
           SetProperty(ref _task.Subject, value)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, it seems, there are no benefits in this case and it's the same approach as usage of direct OnPropertyChanged method. Also if Subject property support TwoWay mode we have to implement SaveData method.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
class TaskViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private readonly Task _task;
    private string _subject;

    public TaskViewModel(Task task)
    {
        _task = task;

        Subject = _task.Subject;
    }

    public string Subject
    {
        get { return _subject; }
        set
        {
            _task.Subject = value;
           SetProperty(ref _subject, value)
        }
    }
}
```

**UPD**

I decided to add some explanations after the first comment.

BindableBase is just a basic version of the class that implements `INotifiPropertyChanged` interface. It's an implementation of the `SetProperty` method (for the `Prism` framework):

```
public abstract class BindableBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Some other members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (object.Equals((object) storage, (object) value))
            return false;

        storage = value;

        this.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

        return true;
    }
}
```

As can be seen, the method `SetProperty` if just "syntactic sugar" and the `OnPropertyChanged` is executing inside. Therefore, it does not really matter whether you call the method `SetProperty` or the `OnPropertyChanged`.

Comment: Yes, it's possible workaround, but it seems, much easier just to call raw OnPropertyChanged method instead of creating additional field and calling SetProperty for it.

Comment: Please see updating of my answer. I tried to explain a few things.